# Get RowIndex from nested listview button click - UWP

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

I have a nested listview as shown below. Which shows students name and their corresponding marks in a button. When clicks on button I want to get the clciked row index. How can I get it?

```
  <ListView x:Name="Mainlist" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ClassRoomList">
       <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ListView x:Name="sublist1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind CurrentStudentsArray}" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
              <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:CurrentStudentsList">
                    <Grid>
                       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind StudentName}"/>
                               <ListView x:Name="sublist2" ItemsSource="{x:Bind StudentsMarksArray}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                                  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                   <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:StudentsMarksList">
                                      <Button Width="120" Height="40" Text="{x:Bind MarkInEnglish}"  Click="ShowDetails_btn_Click">
                                       </Button>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                         </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
              </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

```
 private void ShowDetails_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int selectedIndx = Mainlist.SelectedIndex; //always return -1
}
```

Listview will looks like below,

```
 DIANA 35
 DHAYA 45
 HAYAN 55
```

Class I used is shown below.Its value is binding to an observable collection. And this collection is set as listview's itemsource

```
  namespace TestClass
 {
 public class ClassRoomList
{
    public int ClassID{ get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<CurrentStudentsList> CurrentStudentsArray { get; set; }
}

public class CurrentStudentsList
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<StudentsMarksList> StudentsMarksArray { get; set; }

}
public class StudentsMarksList
{
    public string MarkInEnglish { get; set; }
    public string MarkInMaths{ get; set; }
}
```

}

```
 public static ObservableCollection<ClassRoomList> _ClassRoomList = new ObservableCollection<ClassRoomList>(); //_ClassRoomList  is set as itemsource for Mainlist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get a reference to the parent `ListView` and the parent `ListViewItem` using the `VisualTreeHelper` class. You could then use the `IndexOf` method of `ObservableCollection<CurrentStudentsList>` to get the index:

```
private void ShowDetails_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject depObj = (DependencyObject)sender;
    ListView innerListView = FindParent<ListView>(depObj);
    if (innerListView != null)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = FindParent<ListViewItem>(innerListView);
        if (lvi != null)
        {
            ListView outerListView = FindParent<ListView>(lvi);
            if (outerListView != null)
            {
                ObservableCollection<CurrentStudentsList> students = outerListView.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<CurrentStudentsList>;
                if (students != null)
                {
                    int index = students.IndexOf(lvi.Content as CurrentStudentsList);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

    if (parent == null) return null;

    var parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
}
```

Comment: shows an error , the name "sublist1" does not exist in the current context. Cant access any of inner listview names (sublist1,sublist2) on code behind

Comment: count of student get as 1, and lvi.DataContext is null. what is the reason for it? but I'am getting listview as shown in the question

Comment: So what is the DataContext of lvi?

Comment: it is getting as null

Comment: lvi.Content returns StudentsMarksArray count=1; StudentName= Diana

Comment: I mean lvi.Content  returns " CurrentStudentsList" class. which has  StudentsMarksArray count=1; StudentName= Diana

Comment: So cast `lvi.Content` instead of `lvi.DataContext`. I edited my answer.

Comment: still getting as -1

Comment: But the cast works, i.e. `lvi.Content as CurrentStudentsList` gives you back a `CurrentStudentsList`?

Comment: So what does students return? How many items? Isn't the current item in there?

Comment: students return a count=1. yes it is there

Comment: Did you do something strange in your CurrentStudentsList class then?

Comment: hi, now index is getting as 0 for each rows

Comment: That's expected if students.Count returns 1, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The sender will contain the datacontext of the row item that raised the event. You could handle it in the Click handler:

```
private void ShowDetails_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     StudentMark selectedItem= ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as StudentMark ;
     //If you are specially interested in index you could get it by:
     int index= CurrentStudentsList.StudentsMarksArray.IndexOf(selectedItem);

}
```

`

Comment: how can i get index from this? Getting its data only

Comment: @user2431727 I edited the answer. If you are Ok with that check as answer please, have a good day

Comment: StudentsMarksList selectedItem= ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as StudentsMarksList ;           int index= StudentsMarksList.IndexOf(selectedItem);  shows : "StudentsMarksList doesnot contain definition for IndexOf"

Comment: StudentsMarksList  is not implementing a Collection ?

Comment: yes using observable collection.please see my edited code

Comment: it shows an object reference is required for non static field. But when creating it , shows index error on running

Comment: I want index in CurrentStudentsArray